# Does Sci-kit Learn Clustering model have hidden global state?

Tags: scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I'm trying to cluster some data with the scikit-learn's `AgglomerativeClustering` model.

To determine better parameters, I try different arguments in for loop. It seems only the first result is well distributed, and the other clustering results are too partial, mostly one big cluster (~2000) and other clusters of 1 or 2 element.

My code looks something like following:

```
for n in range(8, 15):
    model = AgglomerativeClustering(n)
    result = do_cluster(model, data_to_cluster)
    show_cluster_result(result)
```

In my `do_cluster` function, I simply do `model.fit_predict(data_to_cluster)`.

I assume that I have to ***reset*** `model` after clustering or something.

Can anyone tell me what I am missing.

---

After reading kind answers, I re-examined my code. My code had a stupid bug which changed some values of `data_to_cluster` during displaying the result (which contains reference to the source data). I deep-copied source data and the bug is gone. I should've checked my code more carefully.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are instantiating a new model with each iteration and therefore no global states are passed between these instances.

If you are unhappy about the clustering try to tweak some of the input parameters of this clustering algorithm (see [API docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering.html)) or experiment with other clustering algorithms ([link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#hierarchical-clustering)).

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly common for hierarchical clustering (and other algorithms) to produce tiny clusters that contain *outlier*. That is why, e.g., DBSCAN has a noise concept. Such data points exist, and they are not well handled as clusters.

So I doubt there is a "global state" causing this. And you can simply narrow the range, and try k=12 only, for example. If you hypothesis were correct, using a single k should be fine.

If you want to better understand the result, look at the dendrogram. It's more informative than just trying different k.